# issue using php to display SQL rows only valued after todays date

Tags: php, sql, date, filter

I am trying to make a table for a school websitethat displays course availability date results from my SQL dtabase as long as the date is not past. It seems to work fine. Courses that start prior to today are not displayed, while courses that have start dates after today are displayed... As long as the start date is not in April, August, or December.. They will not show up. Any ideas? It almost seems as though the code is comparing the first letter of the month as the value to compare to todays date.. Also the "OREDER BY fullstart" does not work.. The fullstart field in the DB contains the date the course starts formatted as: "February 22, 2012". The echo $today at the end displays "February 22, 2012" formatted the same...

My Code:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10"> 

<th>Course Type</th><th>Date</th><th>Instructor</th>
<?php
//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
} 
$today = date("F j, Y");
$courses = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locationtbl WHERE fullstart >= '$today' ORDER BY fullstart"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($courses)) { 
    $coursetype = $row[coursetype]; 
    $fulldates = $row[fulldates]; 
    $instructor = $row[instructor]; 

?> 
    <form name="courses" method="get"> 
    <tr> 
        <td><input name="coursetype" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $coursetype ?>"><?php echo $coursetype ?></td> 
        <td><input name="fulldates" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fulldates ?>"><?php echo $fulldates ?></td> 
        <td><input name="instructor" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $instructor ?>"><?php echo $instructor ?></td> 
    </tr> </form>

<?php 
}
echo $today; 
?> 
</table>
```

Comment: What type of column is `fullstart`? Is it a VARCHAR or TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the field type of fullstart? If it's varchar change it to date and use MySQL standard date format

Comment: fullstart is varchar.. It is actually compiled from user entry drop down fields. One each for "month", "Start date", and "year". those variables are combined in a string:  $fullstart = $month . " " . $start . ", " . $year;  and is layed out as:  "February 23, 2012"

Comment: well you have to change it to date in order to be able to manipulate it,back up your data and start your research hint : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: The question actually pointed me in the right direction.. Thank You djacobson! And thank you both for your input! I had to change that to "date" format, and rewrite the way var $fullstart is created to reflect the "YYYY-MM-DD" format and it all works now.. The correct entries are displayed or not displayed and they are in correct chronological order.